# why break work this way?

Tags: java, for-loop, break

I'm testing a java code and I'de like to print numbers from 1 to 10

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.Random;

public class test2
{   
    test2()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i<10; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(i);
            if (i == 5) 
                break;
            if (i == 6)
                break;  
            System.out.println(i);
            break;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new test2();
    }
}
```

If I remove the last `break`, the code works. But if I don't remove it, only number 0 gets printed. Why?.

Comment: The last break will always execute, so the loop will only run 1 time, and the first time it runs i equals to 0, so it only prints 0.

Comment: This doesn't print the numbers 1 to 10 if you remove the last break. It prints 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5.

Comment: @AndyTurner i will actually just output `00`

Comment: @PhilippSander "*if you remove the last break*".

Comment: @AndyTurner nice edit ;-)

Comment: @PhilippSander I couldn't have edited my comment even if I wanted to - you commented 6 minutes after my comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`break;` breaks out of the loop. Therefore the last break, which has no condition, causes the loop to terminate after the first iteration.

Answer (score 1):

`break;` leaves a loop.

> The break statement has two forms: labeled and unlabeled. You saw the unlabeled form in the switch statement. You can also use an unlabeled break to terminate a for, while, or do-while loop [...]
>
> An unlabeled break statement terminates the innermost switch, for, while, or do-while statement, but a labeled break terminates an outer statement.

Comment: And not using any statement will also _continue_ with the next iteration. No need to use `continue`.

Answer (score 0):

When the control reaches at the final 'break', it doesn't find any condition.So, it will compulsorily break the loop and thus only '0' will be printed.

Also first time within the loop, the control doesn't enter into any of the 'if'.